# Tag URL Duplicate Content

Tags: url, tags

Lots of duplicate Tag URLs has been created in my website due to Tags. How can I remove these duplicate URLs?
Ex: `https://wowlyfstyle.com/tag/macron/` and `https://wowlyfstyle.com/tag/spain/` both will redirect to same page. I have deleted both tags but still showing duplicate in Siteliner.